# How to understand this dendogram

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering

The values in this similarity matrix are based on jaccards coefficient :

```
    a,  b,  c
a,  1, .3, .6
b, .3,  1, .9
c, .6, .9,  1
```

To generate a cluster analysis I used this code :

```
tb = read.csv("c:\\Users\\Adrian\\Desktop\\sim-matrix.csv", row.names=1);
d  = as.dist(tb);
hclust(d);
plot(hclust(d, method="average"));
```

Which generates this dendogram :

[image]

- Why are `a` & `b` grouped close together
- How is closeness measured ?
- Does the agglomeration method `"average"`, average the corresponding values for `a` , `b` & `c`  ?

`?hclust` does not provide any details

Comment: What do you expect the plot to look like?  `a` and `b` should be much closer to each other than either one to `c`... Also, the beauty of open source software is that you can always go look at the source code .

Comment: @Justin ive updated the question, how is closeness measured, why is a closer to b ?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know, what `d  = as.dist(tb);` does, but I think `hclust(d, method="average")` assumes `d` to be a distance matrix.

> Why are a & b grouped close together

If you provide a similarity matrix the **low similarity** of `.3` between `a` and `b` **is interpreted as a low distance**, thus a high similarity. That would explain why `a` and `b` are grouped first.

> How is closeness measured?

Since you provided the similarity matrix, I think you are referring to how the closeness of clusters is measured when using average linkage. Assuming that the first point is appropriate, average linkage (I think in hclust average is WPGMA) takes the average similarities between all observations in distinct clusters. Lets check that:

**Step 1:**

Average similarities

- `a-b`: `.3`
- `a-c`: `.6`
- `c-b`: `.9`

So we merge `a` and `b` at `.3`

**Step 2:**

Average similarities

- `ab-c`: `(.6 + .9) / (2*1) = 1.5 / 2 = .75`

So merging `ab-c` should be at `.75`. Well, either the calculation of mine is wrong or the dendrogram corresponds to complete linkage.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you never say at any point to your code that this is a **similarity** index. In fact you specifically say the opposite: `as.dist(d)`. `hclust` takes a matrix of distance, i. e. **dissimilarity**. The simplest way to go for you is:

```
tb <- matrix(c(1,.3,.6,.3,1,.9,.6,.9,1),nrow=3)
tb <- 1-tb #Similarity to dissimilarity
d <- as.dist(tb)
plot(hclust(d))
```

Closeness (as you asked) was measured when you measured your Jaccard index.